# SwingX fading effect on JXFrame?

Tags: java, swing, swingx

I tried the demo of the swingx framework (http://swingx.java.net/). When you close the main window you have a great fading effect. I tried to reach this effect with the JXFrame but it has just the normal closing effect.

Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks :-)

It's not related to JXFrame (could be done with any Window), just a timeline bound to the window's opacity property. This timeline is started when the application window is closed, the relevant code is in [DemoUtils](http://java.net/projects/swinglabs-demos/sources/svn/show/trunk/SwingXSet6/swingxset/src/org/jdesktop/swingxset/util?rev=1294)

```
public static void fadeOutAndDispose(final Window window,
        int fadeOutDuration) {
    fadeOutAndEnd(window, fadeOutDuration, false);
}

public static void fadeOutAndExit(Window window, int fadeOutDuration) {
    fadeOutAndEnd(window, fadeOutDuration, true);
}

private static void fadeOutAndEnd(final Window window, int fadeOutDuration, 
        final boolean exit) {
    Timeline dispose = new Timeline(new WindowFader(window));
    dispose.addPropertyToInterpolate("opacity", 1.0f,
            0.0f);
    dispose.addCallback(new UIThreadTimelineCallbackAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onTimelineStateChanged(TimelineState oldState,
                TimelineState newState, float durationFraction,
                float timelinePosition) {
            if (newState == TimelineState.DONE) {
                if (exit) {
                    Runtime.getRuntime().exit(0);
                } else {
                    window.dispose();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    dispose.setDuration(fadeOutDuration);
    dispose.play();
}

public static class WindowFader {
    private Window window;

    public WindowFader(Window window) {
        this.window = window;
    }

    public void setOpacity(float opacity) {
        AWTUtilitiesWrapper.setWindowOpacity(window, opacity);
    }
}
```

Note that the fading effect will no longer work for all frames in jdk7, as the behaviour was changed to effect only undecorated windows

**Edit**

Timeline (and the callbackAdapter) are classes in Trident, one of Kirill's projects, unfortunately abandoned by him, taken over as Insubstantial (don't have a reference handy, sorry) - but you can take any other or handcode a Timer

Comment: thank you, I tried to implement that in my code but missed some classes like Timeline and UIThreadTImelineCallbackAdapter ... Is there maybe a library that I miss?